# May RedirectUris use localhost in production?

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.0

Silly question... in the example shown below redirect user to localhost
i.e http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc

On my production would I need to change this to 
https://app.domain.com/signin-oidc ?

http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/6_aspnet_identity.html

```
new Client
{
ClientId = "mvc",
ClientName = "MVC Client",
AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,

RequireConsent = false,

ClientSecrets =
{
    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
},

RedirectUris           = { "http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc" },
PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002/signout-callback-oidc" },

AllowedScopes =
{
    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
    "api1"
},
AllowOfflineAccess = true
}
```

Comment: Yes, localhost should only be used for testing when the client is a web app. Don't include localhost redirect uris in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect URLs should be available for clients.

If in a production environment you expect communication with clients located not on the same machine, then yes, these URLs should be publicly accessible over your target network.